# Geopy error extracting country from longitude and latitude

Tags: python, function, keyerror, geopy

I have a dataset with about 45,000 rows and containing 2 columns one for latitude and another for longitude and I'm trying to get name of country according to the data using this function:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgtDR.png

I observed the following :

- when there is a null value, it returns error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raw'`
- when there is a value of 0, it returns error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raw'`
- when there is a value by Negative like this (-113.00000), it returns:
  `KeyError: 'country'`

How Can I fix this please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @basel hany code should never be pasted as image. Please copy and paste your code to the question as selectable text.

Comment: "when there is a null value" ... what's the variable taking value null, 0, negative ?